# Tint color behind UIPopoverController on iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiappearance

we are displaying a UIPopoverController on top of a map and some other UIBarButtonItems. We have removed the gray backdrop (Using C630PopoverBackgroundView) as we want the user to able to interact with the map while still seeing the search results. However the tint color of all the items in the view behind the popover changes to gray until the popover is dismissed. This happens on iOS 7 but not on iOS 8.

Is there any way around this please?

Answer (score 1):

Tapping anywhere outside of a `UIPopoverController` or `UIPopoverPresentationController` will normally dismiss it, and therefore items underneath it are not interactive. The fact that the tint color changes for iOS 7 but not iOS 8 is a result of an issue in iOS 8. It is expected behavior the tint color desaturates in order to indicate the buttons' non-interactive state.

If you would like some elements to be interactive while the popover is presented, you can specify those elements in the `passthroughViews` array. Those elements should not be desaturated.